# ggplot - add lines to plot - between points, not going through points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add lines to an existing plot.
Just ignore the data that is not plotted.
`geom_abline` lets me add lines but they go through the whole graph.
How can I crop the lines that they are only plotted e.g. between (0,0) and (10,-10)?

```
library(ggplot2)
  x <- c(2,4,6,4,7,5,3)
y <- c(4,5,6,7,8,6,4)
data <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
ggplot(data, aes(x= x, y= y)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(25, -60), x = c(20,-5)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = -1) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = -.5, linetype="dotted")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(2,4,6,4,7,5,3)
y <- c(4,5,6,7,8,6,4)
data <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
ggplot(data, aes(x= x, y= y)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(25, -60), x = c(20,-5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 10, y = 0, yend = 0 - 1*10)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 10, y = 0, yend = 0 - 0.5*10),
               linetype = 2)
```